# Row comparison of Old and Updated Excel worksheets

Tags: excel

I tried comparing rows between two Excel 2016 worksheets (Old and Updated) with conditional formatting but it’s rather cumbersome so I’d be grateful for something faster/easier. I tried finding an answer in SO but didn’t find one, sorry if there is one and I missed it…

Old and Updated worksheets have unique IDs for each row so I want to identify the rows with the same ID, compare then and then highlight the differences between them (“new” rows in the Updated worksheet should be ignored).

The initial example might have been confusing so I wrote a new more detailed one, hope it makes more sense now…

1. There are two separate Excel files, OLD.xls and UPDATED.xls (new entries are always added in UPDATES.xls but should be ignored).
2. Both files have identical layout; column A has the ID for the row, columns B-E have text, data start from row 2.
3. Get the ID from OLD row 2 and look for it in UPDATED.
4. Let’s say OLD row 2 ID was found in UPDATED row 10; must check UPDATED cells B10, C10, D10 and E10 and compare them with OLD cells 2B, 2C, 2D and 2E in order to highlight the ones that got updated.

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the data begins on row 2, and that the first column contains the IDs, and that the sheets are called "old" and new", and that there are 4 columns of letters and 100 rows. Then put this conditional formatting formula on the new sheet:

```
=B2<>VLOOKUP($A2,old!$A$2:$E$101,COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't make this work, I'm getting #REF! results for all cells.... more info perhaps?

Comment: Make sure when applying conditional formatting that you select from one example cell and drag across to the other cells. THen make sure to build the formula as if you were in that first cell. In this example, I assumed you were selecting from B2 onward.

Comment: Also, you will need to modify the references so it refers to the where the data actually is. I indicated my assumptions in the answer.

Comment: I actually build a text file with your assumptions to quickly test it, that's why I was surprised it didn't work... I added a more detailed example in my post, perhaps it's clearer now what I'm after in case it wasn't the first time....

Comment: If I have time tomorrow, I'll have another go.